# How to sort integer array in descending order (but starting at index 0 and moving up)?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, indexing, binary-search

my question has to do with sorting an integer array into descending order, but I've got a very specific problem and was wondering if there's a way to solve it without destroying the binary search function I also implemented.

My project overall is perfect, but has one problem which is a dealbreaker according to my instructor. I read a txt file into an array and list them, then sort them into descending order, and have a function to binary search for what index a number is in. My numbers are sorted in descending order and print as such (144, 115, 100, 89, etc). This is GOOD. This is what we want. But when reading the index, 144 is listed as index[19], 115 as index[18] and so on. This is BAD. I would like to maintain the exact same output, but have the highest number be at index[0], then index[1], and be ordered like that.

[Here is a picture of what my program looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0HSu.png)

I'm a little confused as to how to accomplish this. I've tried a few things but regardless of how I do the sorting, the highest numbers are at the highest point on the index.

Here are the relevant bits of my code.

```
int binarySearch(int array1[], int p, int r, int num) {
    if (p <= r) {
        int mid = (p + r) / 2;
        if (array1[mid] == num)
            return mid;
        if (array1[mid] > num)
            return binarySearch(array1, p, mid - 1, num);
        if (array1[mid] < num)
            return binarySearch(array1, mid + 1, r, num);
    }
    return -1;
}

int main() {

    int array1[20]{}; //The array that stores the numbers.
    char letters[15]{}; //The array that stores the characters.
    ifstream inputData("input.txt"); //This assumes input.txt is stored in the same folder.
    int n = 0; //Counter for the arrays
    int num; //This is for the binary search function.
    char x{};


    // Error checking for making sure the file can open
    if (!inputData)
    {
        cout << "Cannot open file.\n";
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        cout << "The unsorted list of integers: \n";
        for (int n = 0; n <= 19; n++) {
            inputData >> array1[n];
            if (inputData.fail()) break;
            cout << array1[n] << " ";

        }

        cout << "\n\nThe sorted list of integers in descending order: \n";
        int n = sizeof(array1) / sizeof(array1[n]); //I have also tried replacing this line with just "int n = 20" and it didn't appear to make any real difference.
        sort(array1, array1 + n);
        for (int n = 19; n >= 0; n--)
            cout << array1[n] << " ";

//When copy-pasting my code across I might be missing a curly bracket or two, don't worry about that stuff.

        cout << "\n \nEnter an integer to search: ";
        cin >> num;
        int index = binarySearch(array1, 0, n - 1, num);
        if (index == -1) {
            cout << num << " could not be found. Please restart the program and try another number.";
        }
        else {
            cout << "Integer " << num << " found at index [" << index << "] in the sorted integer array.";
        }
```

I feel like I must be missing something obvious. Please help, because I cannot get this array working properly. Occasionally when I mess about, it also stops my binary search from working properly, and it can't detect anything, so I need to tread carefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code, you sort the array with

```
sort(array1, array1 + n);
```

That will be ordered using the less-than `<` operator, which will sort it in *ascending* order.

But when you display it:

```
for (int n = 19; n >= 0; n--)
    cout << array1[n] << " ";
```

which you do in *reverse* order (making it seem like it's sorted in descending order). If you display it in the right order, from `0` to `19` then it will be shown in the actual sorted order.

To sort in descending order you need to use [`std::greater`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/greater) instead:

```
std::sort(array1, array1 + n, std::greater{})
```

And display in the correct order:

```
for (int value : array1)
    std::cout << value << ' ';
```

Comment: Thanks, your explanation is clear and seems like an easy fix. But when trying to use std::greater I get an error telling me "argument list for class template "std::greater" is missing". Do you know what I need to include to fix this?

Comment: @JadronAU `std::greater{}` is C++17 syntax. In C++14 you need `std::greater<>{}` before then you need `std::greater<int>{}`

Comment: Great, that works, thank you. When applying this solution it breaks my binary search and means it can't detect anything. I'm still experimenting with a solution as we speak, but do you have any ideas? As soon as I apply the greater<>{} it breaks the binary search and I'm a bit puzzled as to what the correlation between them even is.

Comment: @JadronAU Probably because your binary search assumes an *ascending* order. For `if (array1[mid] > num)` you look at the *lower* half (with the lower indexes), when it should be the opposite.

Comment: Ah, looks like a quick switcharoo of the < and > is what was needed. Thanks mate, you're the best.